# If the interior of $A$ is empty, must $A$ be countable?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a second metrizable space and $A$ is a subset of $X$. If the interior of $A$ is empty, must $A$ be countable?

Thanks!

Comment: $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : \lVert x\rVert = 1\}$

Comment: Or Cantor set as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Try $A=\mathbb R$ and $X=\mathbb R^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is false in *every* uncountable separable space; in particular, every uncountable, second countable, metrizable space.

Let $E$ be a countable dense subset (think of the rationals). Then $E^c$ is necessarily uncountable. Since every nonempty open set contains a point of $E$, $E^c$ must have empty interior.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $\Bbb R$. Take the Cantor set, or the irrationals.